# Lebesgue ball integral and $r^n$ terms

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, volume

So I'm trying to understand how to calculate ball integrals in measure theoretic way:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,r)} \frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}}dx$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}} \chi_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,r)} (x)dx$

$=r^n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{|rx|^{\alpha}} \chi_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,r)} (rx)dx$
$=...$

as written in [this](https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/files/real_analysis.pdf), page 3.

First two lines are clear, but I don't understand what happens in the third line. $r^n$ comes from somewhere, one adds $r$ inside $\chi$ and then there's $r^{\alpha}$ added to the integrand. What, why?

---

The linked paper also has this short theorem or lemma on top of p. 3, which gives a formula for

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(|x|)dx=\omega_{n-1} \int_0^{\infty} f(r)r^{n-1} dr$$

I wonder if this can be found elsewhere?

Comment: It was a change of variable. The $x$ in the second line and the $x$ in the third line are not the same variable. If you want to call the second variable $y$ instead, they used $x=ry$. The Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ scales by $r^n$, which is where that factor came in.

Comment: @NinadMunshi What you mean "scales by $r^n$"?

Comment: Intuitively, If I have a box and decide to double all of the dimensions, then the volume got bigger by $2^3$

Comment: if you're not familiar with change of variables in multiple dimensions, you should probably check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Comment: It's ultimately no different from the fact that $\int_a^b f(x)\textrm{d}x=\int_{a/r}^{b/r} rf(ry)\textrm{d}y$ with the change of variables $x=ry$.

Comment: I know that $m_n(B(0,r))=\omega_n r^n$, where $\omega_n = m_n(B(0,1))$. However, in the three lines above, I don't see that there's change from $B(0,r)$ to $B(0,1)$.

Comment: No, but the map $x\mapsto rx$ is a bijection $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto itself, so your domain of integration doesn't change, but look at what happens to the characteristic function in your example.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou So, on 2nd line: if $x \in (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,r))$, on 3rd line: if $rx \in (\mathbb{R^n} \setminus B(0,r))$. Means?

Comment: Yeah, so your author has terrible notation for readability. The integration variable should have another name in the third line, say, $y$ and then, the two integrals are related by the relation $x=ry$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou You can still explain it using some better notation. I still don't understand why we scale by $r^n$. And this is the only resource I've found. My intuition says that "since we're now looking at $rx$, then we're essentially looking at the same thing, but with $r^n$ scale factor", but this is "intuition", not rigorous.

Comment: Did you read the wiki-page that I linked?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Yes, but this task should not require determinants.

Comment: It definitely should. Our matrix here is just going to be diagonal, with all $r$'s as diagonal entries.